# retrieve back image from sql server database and display in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

i stored  few images in database in binary format, now i want to display those images in my view,how can we convert those images from binary format to image format again?

this is my action menthod in my controller

```
           public ActionResult DislpayAllImage()
           {
            DataSet dsa = new DataSet();
            dsa = objImage.getAllImages();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = dsa.Tables[0];
            if (dt != null)
            {
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                Byte[] image = (Byte[])dt.Rows[i]["UsImage"];
                return File(image, "image/jpg");
             }
            }
        return View();



    }
```

this is my code in model

```
     public DataSet getUserImage(int Id)
     {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        try
        {
            DbCommand db = dbcon.GetStoredProcCommand("GetImage");
            dbcon.AddInParameter(db, "@Id", DbType.Int16, Id);
            db.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            return ds = dbconstr.ExecuteDataSet(dbCmd);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return ds = null;
        }
    }
```

view

```
 @foreach( var image in ViewData.Images )
 {
  <img src="@Url.Action("DislpayImage", "Home",new { id = image.ImageID })" />
 }
```

how can i display my image in razor view,also is the above code fine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call your Controller's Action(`DislpayImage()`) from the View like this:

```
<img src="<%= Url.Action("DislpayImage", "Controller") %>" alt="myimage" />
```

or

```
<img src="@Url.Action("DislpayImage", "Controller")" alt="myimage" />
```

Hope it helps you.

---

**Edit**

Just pass the id of the image you want to display to Controller action

```
public ActionResult DislpayImage(int id)
     {
        DataSet dsa = new DataSet();

        dsa = objImage.getUserImage(id);
        var imagedata = dsa.Tables[0].Columns["MyImage"];
        return File(imagedata, "image/jpg");

     }
```

Now pass the id of image which you want to display in your view, like this:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("DislpayImage", "Controller", new { id="2" })" alt="myimage" />
```

Now you will get the image with id as 2.

Comment: If there is no image then `myimage` text will be displayed, your can remove that

Comment: I'm getting error in this line return File(imagedata, "image/jpg"); as'the best overload method ....has some invalid arguments,

Comment: try this `byte[] imagedata` instead of `var imagedata`

Comment: here im getting the error as  cannot implicitly convert system.data.datacolumn to byte[]

Comment: so, try like this `byte[] imagedata=(byte[])dsa.Tables[0].Columns["MyImage"];`

Comment: im getting  error now as, cannot convert type system.data.datacolumn to byte[]

Comment: Try debugging and see what are you getting in `dsa.Tables[0].Columns["MyImage"];
`

Comment: @colorsbright did you get the binary data in your dataset image column

Comment: now i got it...i converted the dataset to datatable and the below 2 lines did the work for me,  Byte[] image = (Byte[])dt.Rows[0]["UsImage"];
  return File(image, "image/jpg");

Comment: this is displaying 1 image, now if i want to display all the images as a gallery, i vl get all the images as binary data and how to change the view?

Comment: if you want to display all of them use `foreach` or `for`

Comment: i have edited my controller code and view code in my post, the problem is in forloop the file is being returned and only the 1st image is being displayed in controller code

Answer (score 0):

```
<% foreach( var image in ViewData.Images ) { %> 
  <%= Html.Image( Url.Action( "Show", "Image", new { id = image.ImageID } ) ) %> 
<% } %>



 public class ImageController : Controller

    {

        public void Show(string id)

        {

           Image image = GetImage(id);


           Response.Buffer = True;
           Response.Clear();
           Response.ContentType = "image/gif";
           Response.BinaryWrite( image.Data );
           Response.End();

       }

    }
```

This response is just a copy of an answer from another forum.
This is not my own. I'm pasting it here to help you and someone else in this forum
with the same issue.

Here is the main link: http://forums.asp.net/post/2264885.aspx